# How to remove string replication with SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have created a table with a `author` field as a *string*, but then I realized that there should be another table and author should be a foreign key pointing to that table.

```
CREATE TABLE post (
  id SERIAL INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  author VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE author (
  id SERIAL INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
)
```

Now, I am curious how to move the author data from `post` table to `author`, I have written this so far:

```
ALTER TABLE post ADD COLUMN author_id;
INSERT INTO author (name) SELECT author FROM post;
```

But how to make `post.author_id` to point to the correct rows in `author` table? I have tried this:

```
update post
set author_id = author.id
from post p
inner join author
on p.author = author.name;
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server) questoion, but after executing that all rows in `post` are now pointing to `author 1`! Then I thought I have to add where clause:

```
update post
set author_id = author.id
from post p
inner join author
on p.author = author.name
where author.name = p.author;
```

But again this produced the exact result from the previous SQL.

Where am I going wrong? Can you please point me to the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you don't want an explicit `join`.  That is, you want to mention the `post` table only once:

```
update post p
    set author_id = a.id
from author a
where p.author = a.name;
```

The multiple mentions to `post` are *separate*, which means the query is doing:

```
post cross join
post p join
author a
```